OVH to Hetzner GRE Tunnel Working, But There Are Some Issues
I am trying to make OVH IPv4 addresses usable on Hetzner. This way, I get OVH protection and don't have to obtain IPv4 addresses from Hetzner.
The GRE tunnel IPv4 addresses I obtained from Noez.de work flawlessly on Hetzner, and I can distribute them perfectly to my virtual servers.
However, when distributing the server and IPv4 addresses I obtained from OVH, I don't experience issues locally but do encounter problems on the public network.
First of all, please don’t refer to the following topics as I’ve already researched and tried them:
https://wiki.buyvm.net/doku.php/gre_tunnel
https://lowendtalk.com/discussion/156850/howto-tunnel-ddos-protected-ovh-ip-to-vms-in-other-datacenter/p1
https://lowendtalk.com/discussion/185975/ip-tunneling-from-ovh-to-hetzner
Noez.de directly routes the IPv4 addresses to my endpoint server, and with the commands below, I can accept them and route them to the network interface I created without any issues. This way, anyone with that network interface can use the IPv4 addresses (without needing a special IPv4 address).
variables:
noez_ipv4 = "22.22.22.22"
special_nonexistent_gateway_address = "222.222.222.1"
created_interface = "ens224"
commands:
ip rule add from noez_ipv4 table 20 prio 1
ip addr add special_nonexistent_gateway_address/24 dev created_interface
ip route add default src special_nonexistent_gateway_address dev gre1 table 20
With these commands, my router server is ready. When I select this ens224 network adapter for my virtual servers, they can start using the 22.22.22.22 IPv4 address.
I don't know how Noez achieved this and would like to learn. Is there anyone who can help me with this?
BuyVM does this via NAT, but GRE tunnel servers can directly connect to each other.
For example, let’s say BUYVM endpoint server: 1.1.1.1 and the endpoint server using the IP: 2.2.2.2.
When using the BuyVM NAT method, when we connect to 1.1.1.1, we are actually connecting to 2.2.2.2, but this happens directly between the two servers. I don’t want this. Noez seems to have managed this and I’m curious how they did it. Because when I connect to Noez’s endpoint server, my endpoint server is not reachable. However, I can use Noez’s IPv4 addresses without any issues.


Noez seems to have managed this and I’m curious how they did it.

From your description, it seems that their setup isn't anything special – rather, it is the most basic kind of IP routing there is. It's how IP works when there's no NAT.

Suppose your hosting provider gives you a server with the primary address 11.11.11.11 and the same provider also gives you 22.22.22.0/24 – they would do the equivalent of ip route add 22.22.22.0/24 via 11.11.11.11 on their gateway to let your server use those addresses.

Similarly, if the hosting provider gives you only the addresses 22.22.22.0/24 for use "somewhere else" via GRE tunnel, then they can achieve this by 1) creating the GRE tunnel interface on their side, and 2) doing ip route add 22.22.22.0/24 [via whatever] dev gre-keljix.


(GRE tunnels are "layer 3" or "IP layer" interfaces, so they don't really need a gateway address to be specified, as there's only one place that packets could go to anyway: the other end of the tunnel. Therefore, although it's traditional to assign a /30 or /31 for the tunnel, it's optional – and Noez doesn't really need to know what address you've configured on your end of the tunnel, if any; they can just route through dev gre-keljix.)

ip addr add special_nonexistent_gateway_address/24 dev created_interface

If you add the address using ip addr add, it is no longer "nonexistent". The machine that you've added the address to literally becomes the gateway.

I think the IPv4 addresses at OVH are announced via BGP. I can add the additional IPs they provide with a /32. If I succeed in this, in the future, I will BGP announce my own /24 IP addresses to OVH and create a GRE tunnel to Hetzner.
What I mean by "non-existent" is this: the Gateway IP address only appears to exist locally; it won't respond to pings from the outside or send them. It is just a gateway address for procedural purposes. No matter what I write, it will work. The reason I do this is to give my virtual server clients a gateway address they can access.
I continue below.

I will record and send a video shortly. You’ll understand what I mean better. Thank you for your response.
Before I record the video, can you tell me how to forward my 55.55.55.251 IPv4 address on OVH to my Hetzner endpoint server and how to use it?
Because after the forwarding, when I enter the ip rule and route commands on my Hetzner server, and then use ip addr to add it, the IP address does not respond to pings from the outside (from my home internet) when pinging between the endpoint servers.
